# White spaces in the html for email design using table tags

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html style="opacity: 1;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport" />
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i');
    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
      color: inherit !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      font-size: inherit !important;
      font-family: inherit !important;
      font-weight: inherit !important;
      line-height: inherit !important;
    }
    
    img {
      display: block;
      border-style: none;
      line-height: 0px;
    }
    
    div,
    p,
    a,
    li,
    td,
    th {
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }
    
    table {
      display: table;
      border-spacing: 0px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    td {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .two-column .contents {
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .two-column img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .two-column .text {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .two-column {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 0;
    }
    
    .two-column .column {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 294px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .contents {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .mobile-show {
      display: none !important;
      font-size: 0 !important;
      max-height: 0 !important;
      line-height: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      mso-hide: all !important;
      /* hide elements in Outlook 2007-2013 */
    }
    
    .IconText {
      font-size: 11px!important;
      line-height: 13px!important;
    }
    
    input {
      display: none !important;
    }
    
    input[id=effect]+div[class=em_show_g] {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .button {
      background-color: #F7E3DA;
      border: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 16px;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      background-color: #FFC9FF;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
      .mobalign {
        text-align: center !important;
      }
      .FullWidth {
        width: 100%!important;
        height: auto;
      }
      .mobile-hide {
        display: none;
      }
      .mobile-show {
        display: block !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
        width: auto !important;
        max-height: inherit !important;
      }
      .mobile-brands {
        width: 95% !important;
        max-width: 95% !important;
      }
      .StackColumn {
        display: block;
        width: 100% !important;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .OneFromTwo {
        display: block;
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      .CentreText {
        text-align: center!important;
      }
      .CTA-Full {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      .SpacerHeight {
        width: 1px;
        height: 35px;
      }
      input[id=effect]+div[class=em_show_g] {
        display: none;
      }
      input[id=effect]:checked+div[class=em_show_g] {
        display: block !important;
        height: auto !important;
        width: auto !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
      }
      .button {
        background-color: #F7E3DA;
        border: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 16px;
      }
      .button:hover {
        background-color: #FFC9FF;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!--[if mso]>
<style>
span, td, th, table, div, a {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body background="" bgcolor="#eceef3" style="">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; display: none; float: left">
    <tr>
      <td height="1" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; padding: 0px;">
        <!--Start BK pixel-->
        <IMG SRC="" HEIGHT="1" WIDTH="1" /><br/><br/>
        <!--End BK pixel-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<![endif]-->
  <!--<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
<tr>
<td align="center">-->
  <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content" style="margin:0 auto; table-layout:fixed; max-width:600px; width:100%; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; background:#ffffff; font-weight: 300;">
    <!-- Preheader -->
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%">
          <div data-content-region-name="Pre_Header">
            <!-- Preheader -->
            <tr class="mobile-hide">
              <td align="center">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#1e1e1e; font-weight: 300; font-size:12px; line-height:18px; padding:20px;" width="100%">
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Pre-Header End -->
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th align="center">
          <table align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background:#ffffff;" width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th align="left" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px;" width="50%">
                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="FullWidth" width="170">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th align="center" width="20">
                          <a href="#" rilt="iOS-Icon-EN" target="_blank"><img alt="" border="0" height="20" src="" style="display: block; padding-right: 5px" width="16" /></a>
                        </th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 20px">
                          <a href="#" rilt="" target="_blank"><img alt="" border="0" height="20" src="" style="display: block;" width="16" /></a>
                        </th>

                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </th>
                <th align="right" style="padding-right: 20px" width="50%">
                  <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="FullWidth" width="150">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th align="right" width="23">
                          <a href="#" rilt="View-Online-Icon-EN" style="color:#1E1E1E; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="View in browser" border="0" class="mobile-hide" height="16" src="" style="display: block;" width="23" /></a>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <!-- Header Image End -->
      <!-- Header -->

      <!-- Header Image End -->
      <!-- Desktop Navigation -->

      <!-- Desktop Navigation End -->
      <!-- Content Starts Here -->



      <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td style="max-width:600px; width:100%; font-size:0px;" style="display:block; line-height:0px;">
          <table style="max-width:600px; width:100%; line-height:0px; display:block; ">
            <tr>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px; font-size:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td style="max-width:600px; width:100%; font-size:0px;" style="display:block; line-height:0px;">
          <table style="max-width:600px; width:100%; line-height:0px; display:block; ">
            <tr>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px; font-size:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td style="max-width:600px; width:100%; font-size:0px;" style="display:block; line-height:0px;">
          <table style="max-width:600px; width:100%; line-height:0px; display:block; ">
            <tr>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px; font-size:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td style="max-width:600px; width:100%; font-size:0px;" style="display:block; line-height:0px;">
          <table style="max-width:600px; width:100%; line-height:0px; display:block; ">
            <tr>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px; font-size:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td style="max-width:600px; width:100%; font-size:0px;" style="display:block; line-height:0px;">
          <table style="max-width:600px; width:100%; line-height:0px; display:block; ">
            <tr>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px; font-size:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td style="max-width:600px; width:100%; font-size:0px;" style="display:block; line-height:0px;">
          <table style="max-width:600px; width:100%; line-height:0px; display:block; ">
            <tr>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="50%" height="auto" align="center" style="line-height:0px; font-size:0px;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img style="display:block;border:0;" src="" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

I've been trying to design an email template which has images. I use table structure to create the email with HTML and CSS. However, I see white lines between the images in different platforms. I don't have a problem in Gmail desktop, but I see white lines when opened in Gmail mobile app. How can this be fixed? I've also tried adding `display: block;` and `font-size: 0px;` but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code brother

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Simple Transactional Email</title>
    <style>
      /* -------------------------------------
          GLOBAL RESETS
      ------------------------------------- */
      
      /*All the styling goes here*/
      
      img {
        border: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        max-width: 100%; 
      }

      body {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.4;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
      }

      table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
        mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        width: 100%; }
        table td {
          font-family: sans-serif;
          font-size: 14px;
          vertical-align: top; 
      }

      /* -------------------------------------
          BODY & CONTAINER
      ------------------------------------- */

      .body {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        width: 100%; 
      }

      /* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
      .container {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        /* makes it centered */
        max-width: 580px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 580px; 
      }

      /* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
      .content {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 580px;
        padding: 10px; 
      }

      /* -------------------------------------
          HEADER, FOOTER, MAIN
      ------------------------------------- */
      .main {
        background: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 100%; 
      }

      .wrapper {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px; 
      }

      .content-block {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
      }

      .footer {
        clear: both;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%; 
      }
        .footer td,
        .footer p,
        .footer span,
        .footer a {
          color: #999999;
          font-size: 12px;
          text-align: center; 
      }

      /* -------------------------------------
          TYPOGRAPHY
      ------------------------------------- */
      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4 {
        color: #000000;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.4;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 30px; 
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: capitalize; 
      }

      p,
      ul,
      ol {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 15px; 
      }
        p li,
        ul li,
        ol li {
          list-style-position: inside;
          margin-left: 5px; 
      }

      a {
        color: #3498db;
        text-decoration: underline; 
      }

      /* -------------------------------------
          BUTTONS
      ------------------------------------- */
      .btn {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%; }
        .btn > tbody > tr > td {
          padding-bottom: 15px; }
        .btn table {
          width: auto; 
      }
        .btn table td {
          background-color: #ffffff;
          border-radius: 5px;
          text-align: center; 
      }
        .btn a {
          background-color: #ffffff;
          border: solid 1px #3498db;
          border-radius: 5px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          color: #3498db;
          cursor: pointer;
          display: inline-block;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: bold;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 12px 25px;
          text-decoration: none;
          text-transform: capitalize; 
      }

      .btn-primary table td {
        background-color: #3498db; 
      }

      .btn-primary a {
        background-color: #3498db;
        border-color: #3498db;
        color: #ffffff; 
      }

      /* -------------------------------------
          OTHER STYLES THAT MIGHT BE USEFUL
      ------------------------------------- */
      .last {
        margin-bottom: 0; 
      }

      .first {
        margin-top: 0; 
      }

      .align-center {
        text-align: center; 
      }

      .align-right {
        text-align: right; 
      }

      .align-left {
        text-align: left; 
      }

      .clear {
        clear: both; 
      }

      .mt0 {
        margin-top: 0; 
      }

      .mb0 {
        margin-bottom: 0; 
      }

      .preheader {
        color: transparent;
        display: none;
        height: 0;
        max-height: 0;
        max-width: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        mso-hide: all;
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 0; 
      }

      .powered-by a {
        text-decoration: none; 
      }

      hr {
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
        margin: 20px 0; 
      }

      /* -------------------------------------
          RESPONSIVE AND MOBILE FRIENDLY STYLES
      ------------------------------------- */
      @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
        table[class=body] h1 {
          font-size: 28px !important;
          margin-bottom: 10px !important; 
        }
        table[class=body] p,
        table[class=body] ul,
        table[class=body] ol,
        table[class=body] td,
        table[class=body] span,
        table[class=body] a {
          font-size: 16px !important; 
        }
        table[class=body] .wrapper,
        table[class=body] .article {
          padding: 10px !important; 
        }
        table[class=body] .content {
          padding: 0 !important; 
        }
        table[class=body] .container {
          padding: 0 !important;
          width: 100% !important; 
        }
        table[class=body] .main {
          border-left-width: 0 !important;
          border-radius: 0 !important;
          border-right-width: 0 !important; 
        }
        table[class=body] .btn table {
          width: 100% !important; 
        }
        table[class=body] .btn a {
          width: 100% !important; 
        }
        table[class=body] .img-responsive {
          height: auto !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          width: auto !important; 
        }
      }

      /* -------------------------------------
          PRESERVE THESE STYLES IN THE HEAD
      ------------------------------------- */
      @media all {
        .ExternalClass {
          width: 100%; 
        }
        .ExternalClass,
        .ExternalClass p,
        .ExternalClass span,
        .ExternalClass font,
        .ExternalClass td,
        .ExternalClass div {
          line-height: 100%; 
        }
        .apple-link a {
          color: inherit !important;
          font-family: inherit !important;
          font-size: inherit !important;
          font-weight: inherit !important;
          line-height: inherit !important;
          text-decoration: none !important; 
        }
        #MessageViewBody a {
          color: inherit;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: inherit;
          font-family: inherit;
          font-weight: inherit;
          line-height: inherit;
        }
        .btn-primary table td:hover {
          background-color: #34495e !important; 
        }
        .btn-primary a:hover {
          background-color: #34495e !important;
          border-color: #34495e !important; 
        } 
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="">
    <span class="preheader">This is preheader text. Some clients will show this text as a preview.</span>
    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="container">
          <div class="content">

            <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
            <table role="presentation" class="main">

              <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
              <tr>
                <td class="wrapper">
                  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <p>Hi there,</p>
                        <p>Sometimes you just want to send a simple HTML email with a simple design and clear call to action. This is it.</p>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left">
                                <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td> <a href="http://htmlemail.io" target="_blank">Call To Action</a> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <p>This is a really simple email template. Its sole purpose is to get the recipient to click the button with no distractions.</p>
                        <p>Good luck! Hope it works.</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>

            <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
            </table>
            <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->

            <!-- START FOOTER -->
            <div class="footer">
              <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td class="content-block">
                    <span class="apple-link">Company Inc, 3 Abbey Road, San Francisco CA 94102</span>
                    <br> Don't like these emails? <a href="http://i.imgur.com/CScmqnj.gif">Unsubscribe</a>.
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="content-block powered-by">
                    Powered by <a href="http://htmlemail.io">HTMLemail</a>.
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- END FOOTER -->

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed so OP knows how to fix this in the future.